# How to make the select query comparatively faster in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I was looking for best approach to get this query faster in rails. Currently it takes lots of time due to Geocoder calculations.

```
Vehicle.includes(:user)
       .where.not('users.id' => nil)
       .where(country: 'United Kingdom')
       .where.not(name: [nil, ''])
       .select { |vehicle| 
         vehicle.longitude.present? &&
         Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(
           [vehicle.latitude,vehicle.longitude], 
           [location.latitude,location.longitude]
         ).between?(0, 200)
       }
```

Note: Currently the db used is PostgreSQL 9.5.14.

Comment: Currently the db used is PostgreSQL 9.5.14.

Comment: Have you considered using [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/)? You wouldn't have to load all the records as you would be able to filter directly on DB level using [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html).

Comment: Done; nope haven't tried postgis yet. Currently for the location 'geocoder' gem is used.

Comment: Well, you will have to move the filtering to a database at some point. `vehicle.longitude.present?` could be moved to DB-level, but I suppose that won't help much. Your best bets are either PostGIS or ElasticSearch, imho.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MarcinKołodziej. Also, I guess indexing those fields could boost up the speed. Thoughts?

Comment: Right now you can index only the fields you're searching by (`users.id`,`country`,`name`, etc.), indexing longitudes and latitudes without PostGIS won't help.

Comment: As mentioned by @MarcinKołodziej **PostGIS** is the best and logic solution and any improve won't help because you are fetching lots of data which won't be in use, you can check the example in this link https://medium.com/@hin556/location-based-searching-in-rails-5-part-2-using-postgis-extension-7ab2d34b9885

Comment: Also might want to look at the ["Geospatial Database Queries"](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geospatial-database-queries) section for the README. Seems like you could just add `near([location.latitude,location.longitude], 200, units: :km)` in place of the `select`. Another note `joins(:user)` or `includes(:user).references(:user)` will get rid of the first where by using an inner join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move `vehicle.longitude.present?` to database level:

   ```
   .where.not(longitude: [nil, ''])
   ```
2. Your distance calculation has to be moved to be on database level. Loading all records and calculating distance for each of them in Ruby will be too slow. Simplest solution is to add PostGIS:

   1. Add [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) extension to your database.
   2. (Optional) add  an [adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) that will make it easier to work with the data.
   3. Migrate your existing latitudes/longitudes to `st_point`.
   4. Change your select to a scope which will leverage the [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) function.
3. As an alternative to 2), you may consider moving your distance querying to a search engine like ElasticSearch. I'd only consider that if you will have any performance problems with the complex query you're creating.